# Cannot Add an Utterance with Entities labeled

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to enter an Utterance in [LUIS](http://www.luis.ai), I enter something like

> When is my flight to Chicago?

I then label Chicago as an entity of type `city`

The error on the top bar pops up stating the following

> BadArgument: Character indicies 0,2 do not correspond to the start and end of a token.

I don't know what it means. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you doing your changes inside LUIS portal, or with the API?

Comment: Would you be able to share a JSON of your LUIS model @fahadash? Would like to try to reproduce the error

Comment: @fahadash, without seeing your model, depending on your language, a token is a word. So in your model you must specify the startPos and endPos as the beginning and ending indices of a word